# Golang failes to change the name of imported module

Tags: go, docker, skydns

I'm trying to bring [SkyDNSv1](https://github.com/skynetservices/skydns1) back to life and build it from my fork (here is [Dockerfile](https://github.com/vitalyisaev2/skydns1/blob/master/Dockerfile)). SkyDNS was really good and simple tool for the quick service discovery, but it wasn't updated for a long time.

There is an error in build process and it's caused by third party library. I cannot figure out why does it happen:

```
$ docker build --no-cache -t skydns1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 1.566 MB
Sending build context to Docker daemon 
Step 0 : FROM golang:1.4.2
 ---> 3e8cb8e0c765
Step 1 : WORKDIR /go/src
 ---> Running in 3a06cf460ad9
 ---> 1dd14a099164
Removing intermediate container 3a06cf460ad9
Step 2 : RUN go get github.com/codegangsta/cli
 ---> Running in eabcfd6fe621
 ---> c9ea222f2d74
Removing intermediate container eabcfd6fe621
Step 3 : RUN go get github.com/vitalyisaev2/skydns1
 ---> Running in 3264582b2e7a
# github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb
github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb/influxdb.go:19: undefined: client.ClientConfig
github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb/influxdb.go:38: undefined: client.Series
github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb/influxdb.go:44: undefined: client.Series
github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb/influxdb.go:52: undefined: client.Series
github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb/influxdb.go:60: undefined: client.Series
github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb/influxdb.go:70: undefined: client.Series
github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb/influxdb.go:82: undefined: client.Series
github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb/influxdb.go:93: undefined: client.Series
github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb/influxdb.go:106: client.WriteSeries undefined (type *client.Client has no field or method WriteSeries)
INFO[0075] The command [/bin/sh -c go get github.com/vitalyisaev2/skydns1] returned a non-zero code:
```

But if you look through the [file](https://github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/blob/master/influxdb/influxdb.go#L5) causing this error, you'll notice that Golang is confused about `influxdb/client`. **I think that compiler doesn't replace imported name `client` with `influxClient` as it should do:**

```
package influxdb

import (
    "fmt"
    influxClient "github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client"
    "github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics"
    "log"
    "time"
)
```

Probably I just missing an obvious mistake. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Go compiler doesn't replace or rewrite anything, the code is just wrong. The `github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb` package was written with some other influxdb client code that no longer exists. (Looks like there are a couple github issues open about this already)

If you look at the current [influxdb/client](http://godoc.org/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client) package, you'll see there's no `Series`, `ClientConfig`, or `Client.WriteSeries` at all. You'll need to drop the dependency on `github.com/rcrowley/go-metrics/influxdb` in order to get your project to build.